# Instruments in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, ios4, instruments

I was trying to open instruments in xcode 4 but was not able to find a way to do it. Usually in Xcode 3, we would do run -> run with performance tool... but I dont really find any such thing to do it in xcode 4.. would anyone be able to tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to use Instruments with your product:

Product -> Profile

This brings up a dialog where you can choose Leaks, Allocations, etc.

Answer (score 12):

Cmd-I also works to invoke Profile.

By default Profile is set up to use the Release build.  If you want it to use Debug then pull down the platform dropdown, select "Edit Scheme", go to the "Profile" side-tab, and tell it to use Debug instead of Release.

Answer (score 6):

Product -> Perform Action -> Profile Without Building
This should spawn a dialog to choose the good old known Instrument's templates from.

Comment: "valid provision profile for this executable was not found" error occurs when I click "Profile without building". But I could run the app in the normal way without any provisioning issues. Any idea why?