# Memory leak detection tools in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4, instruments

Where is the memory leak detection tools in Xcode 4?  Or how can I test for memory leaks in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) - see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304390/instruments-in-xcode-4) to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Product -- > Analyze to check your program for memory leaks.

Comment: No - that just runs that static analyser over your code and points out potential problems. This brings up more problems than just memory leaks and is a good first start, but for real memory management you need to run Instruments on the app while it is running on the device.