# Xcode memory leak check

Tags: ios4, memory-leaks, ios5, xcode4.2

I need to check my iPhone application memory leaks. I went following link and I also need to check my app memory leak like that.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R449qEuexNs&feature=related

So can Any one have any idea about how to do this on **Xcode 4.2** ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 4.2 it's under :

Product -> Profile

Answer (score 1):

Check with the following links:

1. [Memory leak detection tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144261/memory-leak-detection-tools-in-xcode)
2. [Instruments in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304390/instruments-in-xcode-4)

It works for me :)

Comment: Xcode: run -> Start with Performance Tool -> Leaks.

could not find in Xcode 4.2

Comment: Check with Product tab-->Profile

Answer (score 1):

You can use shortcut key
**Command + i**