# How to find the memory leak in ios xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ffmpeg

It's my RTSP streaming ios application with FFMPEG decoder and it streaming fine, But the memory continuously increasing while running. Please help me, Is it a memory leak ?. And how can I track the leak ?.

Its my video streaming class: RTSPPlayer.m

```
#import "RTSPPlayer.h"
#import "Utilities.h"
#import "AudioStreamer.h"

@interface RTSPPlayer ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) AudioStreamer *audioController;
@end

@interface RTSPPlayer (private)
-(void)convertFrameToRGB;
-(UIImage *)imageFromAVPicture:(AVPicture)pict width:(int)width height:(int)height;
-(void)setupScaler;
@end

@implementation RTSPPlayer

@synthesize audioController = _audioController;
@synthesize audioPacketQueue,audioPacketQueueSize;
@synthesize _audioStream,_audioCodecContext;
@synthesize emptyAudioBuffer;

@synthesize outputWidth, outputHeight;

- (void)setOutputWidth:(int)newValue
{
    if (outputWidth != newValue) {
        outputWidth = newValue;
        [self setupScaler];
    }
}

- (void)setOutputHeight:(int)newValue
{
    if (outputHeight != newValue) {
        outputHeight = newValue;
        [self setupScaler];
    }
}

- (UIImage *)currentImage
{
    if (!pFrame->data[0]) return nil;
    [self convertFrameToRGB];
    return [self imageFromAVPicture:picture width:outputWidth height:outputHeight];
}

- (double)duration
{
    return (double)pFormatCtx->duration / AV_TIME_BASE;
}

- (double)currentTime
{
    AVRational timeBase = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->time_base;
    return packet.pts * (double)timeBase.num / timeBase.den;
}

- (int)sourceWidth
{
    return pCodecCtx->width;
}

- (int)sourceHeight
{
    return pCodecCtx->height;
}

- (id)initWithVideo:(NSString *)moviePath usesTcp:(BOOL)usesTcp
{
    if (!(self=[super init])) return nil;

    AVCodec         *pCodec;

    // Register all formats and codecs
    avcodec_register_all();
    av_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();

    // Set the RTSP Options
    AVDictionary *opts = 0;
    if (usesTcp) 
        av_dict_set(&opts, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);


    if (avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, [moviePath UTF8String], NULL, &opts) !=0 ) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Couldn't open file\n");
        goto initError;
    }

    // Retrieve stream information
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFormatCtx,NULL) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Couldn't find stream information\n");
        goto initError;
    }

    // Find the first video stream
    videoStream=-1;
    audioStream=-1;

    for (int i=0; i<pFormatCtx->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            NSLog(@"found video stream");
            videoStream=i;
        }

        if (pFormatCtx->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            audioStream=i;
            NSLog(@"found audio stream");
        }
    }

    if (videoStream==-1 && audioStream==-1) {
        goto initError;
    }

    // Get a pointer to the codec context for the video stream
    pCodecCtx = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->codec;

    // Find the decoder for the video stream
    pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pCodecCtx->codec_id);
    if (pCodec == NULL) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Unsupported codec!\n");
        goto initError;
    }

    // Open codec
    if (avcodec_open2(pCodecCtx, pCodec, NULL) < 0) {
        av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Cannot open video decoder\n");
        goto initError;
    }

    if (audioStream > -1 ) {
        NSLog(@"set up audiodecoder");
        [self setupAudioDecoder];
    }

    // Allocate video frame
    pFrame = avcodec_alloc_frame();

    outputWidth = pCodecCtx->width;
    self.outputHeight = pCodecCtx->height;

    return self;

initError:
//  [self release];
    return nil;
}


- (void)setupScaler
{
    // Release old picture and scaler
    avpicture_free(&picture);
    sws_freeContext(img_convert_ctx);   

    // Allocate RGB picture
    avpicture_alloc(&picture, PIX_FMT_RGB24, outputWidth, outputHeight);

    // Setup scaler
    static int sws_flags =  SWS_FAST_BILINEAR;
    img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(pCodecCtx->width, 
                                     pCodecCtx->height,
                                     pCodecCtx->pix_fmt,
                                     outputWidth, 
                                     outputHeight,
                                     PIX_FMT_RGB24,
                                     sws_flags, NULL, NULL, NULL);

}

- (void)seekTime:(double)seconds
{
    AVRational timeBase = pFormatCtx->streams[videoStream]->time_base;
    int64_t targetFrame = (int64_t)((double)timeBase.den / timeBase.num * seconds);
    avformat_seek_file(pFormatCtx, videoStream, targetFrame, targetFrame, targetFrame, AVSEEK_FLAG_FRAME);
    avcodec_flush_buffers(pCodecCtx);
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // Free scaler
    sws_freeContext(img_convert_ctx);   

    // Free RGB picture
    avpicture_free(&picture);

    // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);

    // Free the YUV frame
    av_free(pFrame);

    // Close the codec
    if (pCodecCtx) avcodec_close(pCodecCtx);

    // Close the video file
    if (pFormatCtx) avformat_close_input(&pFormatCtx);

    [_audioController _stopAudio];
   // [_audioController release];
    _audioController = nil;

  //  [audioPacketQueue release];
    audioPacketQueue = nil;

 //   [audioPacketQueueLock release];
    audioPacketQueueLock = nil;

//  [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)stepFrame
{
    // AVPacket packet;
    int frameFinished=0;

    while (!frameFinished && av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >=0 ) {
        // Is this a packet from the video stream?
        if(packet.stream_index==videoStream) {
            // Decode video frame
            avcodec_decode_video2(pCodecCtx, pFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
        }

        if (packet.stream_index==audioStream) {
            // NSLog(@"audio stream");
            [audioPacketQueueLock lock];

            audioPacketQueueSize += packet.size;
            [audioPacketQueue addObject:[NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&packet length:sizeof(packet)]];

            [audioPacketQueueLock unlock];

            if (!primed) {
                primed=YES;
                [_audioController _startAudio];
            }

            if (emptyAudioBuffer) {
                [_audioController enqueueBuffer:emptyAudioBuffer];
            }
        }
    }

    return frameFinished!=0;
}

- (void)convertFrameToRGB
{
    sws_scale(img_convert_ctx,
              pFrame->data,
              pFrame->linesize,
              0,
              pCodecCtx->height,
              picture.data,
              picture.linesize);
}

- (UIImage *)imageFromAVPicture:(AVPicture)pict width:(int)width height:(int)height
{
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CFDataRef data = CFDataCreateWithBytesNoCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, pict.data[0], pict.linesize[0]*height,kCFAllocatorNull);
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(data);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreate(width, 
                                       height, 
                                       8, 
                                       24, 
                                       pict.linesize[0], 
                                       colorSpace, 
                                       bitmapInfo, 
                                       provider, 
                                       NULL, 
                                       NO, 
                                       kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CFRelease(data);

    return image;
}

- (void)setupAudioDecoder
{    
    if (audioStream >= 0) {
        _audioBufferSize = AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE;
        _audioBuffer = av_malloc(_audioBufferSize);
        _inBuffer = NO;

        _audioCodecContext = pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->codec;
        _audioStream = pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream];

        AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_decoder(_audioCodecContext->codec_id);
        if (codec == NULL) {
            NSLog(@"Not found audio codec.");
            return;
        }

        if (avcodec_open2(_audioCodecContext, codec, NULL) < 0) {
            NSLog(@"Could not open audio codec.");
            return;
        }

        if (audioPacketQueue) {
          //  [audioPacketQueue release];
            audioPacketQueue = nil;
        }        
        audioPacketQueue = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        if (audioPacketQueueLock) {
        //    [audioPacketQueueLock release];
            audioPacketQueueLock = nil;
        }
        audioPacketQueueLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];

        if (_audioController) {
            [_audioController _stopAudio];
         //   [_audioController release];
            _audioController = nil;
        }
        _audioController = [[AudioStreamer alloc] initWithStreamer:self];
    } else {
        pFormatCtx->streams[audioStream]->discard = AVDISCARD_ALL;
        audioStream = -1;
    }
}

- (void)nextPacket
{
    _inBuffer = NO;
}

- (AVPacket*)readPacket
{
    if (_currentPacket.size > 0 || _inBuffer) return &_currentPacket;

    NSMutableData *packetData = [audioPacketQueue objectAtIndex:0];
    _packet = [packetData mutableBytes];

    if (_packet) {
        if (_packet->dts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
            _packet->dts += av_rescale_q(0, AV_TIME_BASE_Q, _audioStream->time_base);
        }

        if (_packet->pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE) {
            _packet->pts += av_rescale_q(0, AV_TIME_BASE_Q, _audioStream->time_base);
        }

        [audioPacketQueueLock lock];
        audioPacketQueueSize -= _packet->size;
        if ([audioPacketQueue count] > 0) {
            [audioPacketQueue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
        [audioPacketQueueLock unlock];

        _currentPacket = *(_packet);
    }

    return &_currentPacket;   
}

- (void)closeAudio
{
    [_audioController _stopAudio];
    primed=NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: Use instruments to find memory leak, choose product->profile from the menu and choose leak instrument from the displayed options

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210436/xcode-memory-leak-check

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory leak detection tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144261/memory-leak-detection-tools)

Answer (score 1):

Presented as an answer for formatting and images.

Use instruments to check for leaks and memory loss due to retained but not leaked memory. The latter is unused memory that is still pointed to. Use Mark Generation (Heapshot) in the Allocations instrument on Instruments.

For HowTo use Heapshot to find memory creap, see: [bbum blog](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)

Basically the method is to run Instruments allocate tool, take a heapshot, run an iteration of your code and take another heapshot repeating 3 or 4 times. This will indicate memory that is allocated and not released during the iterations.

To figure out the results disclose to see the individual allocations.

If you need to see where retains, releases and autoreleases occur for an object use instruments:

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on (For Xcode 5 and lower you have to stop recording to set the option). Cause the app to run, stop recording, drill down and you will be able to see where all retains, releases and autoreleases occurred.

[image]